# To do with a bone, soft, Clive's broken (6) (Cryptic Crossword clue help)

Tags: word, cryptic-clues

I recently had the clue "To do with a bone, soft, Clive's broken (6)" in a Cryptic Crossword. I've figured out that the answer is:

> Pelvic

Which I can *partially* explain as:

> 'elvic' is 'Clive' broken (anagrammed)

Can someone help me figure out why:

> Soft means the letter 'p'?

I've left parts of the solution in spoilertags so that if you want, you can try to solve the clue on your own!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In sheet music, *piano* (meaning "play/sing softly")

is denoted as *p*.

> See the [Wikipedia entry on dynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamics_(music))

Comment: Oh, my gosh. I'm in two different orchestras. How did I not make that connection? ._. +1, thanks!

Comment: @BaileyM well *that's* embarrassing! Hehe